# Changing the class name of Google visualization table chart

Tags: jquery, css, charts, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-visualization

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z75X/1/) is a sample Google visualization table chart which is drawn as,

```
  table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Table',
        'dataTable': data,
        'containerId': 'table',
        'options': {
            'width': '100%',
            'showRowNumber' : true
        },
    });
    table.draw();
```

The above Google visualization table chart has a default class name `google-visualization-table-table` and [this link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#Configuration_Options) explains how to customize its individual styles. But how can I change the table's class name itself using jquery to Twitter Bootstrap style? so that, I can customize whole table style using that class name. I tried something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".google-visualization-table-table").attr('class', 'table');
  $("table").addClass( 'table-bordered table-condensed table-striped' );
});
```

But it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's not working? I made a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TdZCy/) and your code (which is run when you click on the table) seems to work as intended

Comment: @dtyler - Find my sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z75X/1/ which have a Google visualization table chart. I want to replace its class name to twitter bootstrap table classes. Also note that it should happen without a click event. ie. inside `$(document).ready(function(){/////});` itself.

Comment: Here is my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z75X/4/ where there is a sample bootstrap table (second table at the result). I trying to achieve that style in first table also. So that i can style it as I required using bootstrap styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the fiddle you provided - see http://jsfiddle.net/8Z75X/2/ for the working demo

Basically, `table.draw();` is happening in the background, so the jquery scripts run and there's no element to change the class of.

Instead, I added a `ready` listener, and ran the jQuery script then, rather than in the document.ready block.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function(){
    $(".google-visualization-table-table").attr('class', 'table');
    $("table").addClass( 'table-bordered table-condensed table-striped' );
    });
```

PS - you may want to try out removeClass instead, and chain your method calls - might be a bit faster

```
$(".google-visualization-table-table")
    .removeClass('google-visualization-table-table')
    .addClass('table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped');
```

Should work just as well, but will only affect this table, not other tables in your page

**Update**

Here is a new version which also removes all the child classes of the table. Its not very efficient to iterate over all the nodes and check each class to see if it starts with 'google-visualization', but I can't think of another way without a full list of all the classes to remove, and calling $() on each item anyway.
http://jsfiddle.net/8Z75X/5/

It also has an extra jQuery call to reset the fixed width that google sets

```
.css("width", "");
```

Just mentioning ... this seems to be a lot of work to go through to reset Google's plugin back towards native html/js - is there a specific function you're looking for? There are plenty of lighter plugins for table sort or filtering, or just pure js/jquery to add rows to a table ...

Comment: It works.. But how to keep the responsive nature of bootstrap to the table like in this sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z75X/4/. Also how to remove all its child's (tr, td, etc) class names in one shot.

Comment: Thanks.. I chosen Google because we can control the output using [Google visualization control wrappers](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) like Categoryfilter Control, ChartRangeFilter Controls etc.

Comment: Also, I think we should fire `statechange` event listener too. Otherwise, if state of the chart changed (eg: when sorting), all the customization vanishes..!